# Confused using Remove-Item with -Recurse AND -Exclude

Tags: powershell

Have a question about Remove-Item and the -Recurse and -Exclude params. On a remote computer, I'd like to recursively remove all subdirectories/files with the exception of one particular file, and yet when I run the following, everything in the parent directory is removed and it seems like the -Exclude parameter is ignored.

`Invoke-Command -Computer MyRemoteComputer -ScriptBlock {Remove-Item $args -Force -Recurse -Exclude 'C:\Folder\Startup.ps1'} -ArgumentList 'C:\Folder\'`

When I look at the [documentation for Remove-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item?view=powershell-6#examples), I do see this line that talks about a known issue, but they don't give any detail as to what the known issue might be.

`Because the Recurse parameter in Remove-Item has a known issue...`

Any suggestions or ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Should work if you change the exclude file to just the filename rather than the full path: `Invoke-Command -Computer MyRemoteComputer -ScriptBlock {Remove-Item $args -Force -Recurse -Exclude 'Startup.ps1'} -ArgumentList 'C:\Folder\'`

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks Owain!

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find what the known issue was but this does seem to work.

> Invoke-Command -Computer MyRemoteComputer -ScriptBlock {Get-ChildItem
>   -Path C:\Folder -Include * -Recurse | Remove-Item -Exclude Startup.ps1 -Recurse -Force}

Because the results of `Get-ChildItem` are what we're deleting we need `-Recurse` to delete all subfolders and their contents, however Remove-Item will not delete the subfolders and contents without specifying `-Recurse` anyway.

Hopefully this avoids the 'known issue' with Recurse on Remove-Item.

Comment: Thanks Dan. In running this, I found that it did delete all the files (except the exclusion) but kept the empty subdirectories.